# MTB Safety - Helmet

Tags: safety, helmets

Does a standard bike helmet offer any real protection when cycling offroad? Looking at other people cycling offroad, fullface helmets are quite rare. Although to me it looks like a standard helmet is almost useless (as well as on road, but even more offroad with all the branches and rocks everywhere). So, any reason fullface is not the standard?

Comment: Anecdotal evidence says yes: I've cracked a standard helmet in half going over the bars on singletrack with no harm to my head... But the linked question will give much better answers.